# tour start as an additional planning variable in Optaplanner VRPTW - a good idea?

Tags: optaplanner

Hi and happy new year to all Optaplanner users,

we have a requirement to plan tours. These tours contain chained and time-windowed activities (deliveries) executed by a weekly changing number of trucks.

The start time of a single tour can vary and is dependent on several conditions (i.e. the goods to be delivered must be produced, before the tour can start; only a limited number of trucks can be served at the plants gates at the same time; truck must be back before starting a new tour). Means: also the order of tours can vary and time gaps between the tours of a truck can occur.

My design plan is, to annotate TourStartTime as a second planning variable in Optaplanners VRPTW-example and to assign TourStartTime to 2-hours time grains (planning horizon is 1 week and tours normally do not start during night times; so the mentioned time grains reflect a simplified calendar for possible tour starts).

The number of available trucks (from external logistic companies) can vary from week to week. Regarding this I wanted to plan with a 'unlimited' number of trucks. But the number of trucks per logistic company, that can be actually assigned with deliveries, should be controlled by a constraint (i.e. 'trucks_to_be_used_in_parallel').

Can anybody tell me, if this is a feasable design approach, or where do I have to avoid traps (ca. 1000 deliveries/week, 40-80 trucks per day) ?

Thank you
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second planning variable is possible (and might be even the best design depending on your requirements), but it will blow up the search space and maybe even custom course grained moves might become needed to get great results.

Instead, I 'd first investigate if the Truck's TourStartTime can be made a **shadow variable**. For example, give all trucks a unique priority number. Then make a Truck's TourStartTime a shadow variable: the soonest time a truck can leave. If there are only 3 lanes and 4 trucks want to leave, the 3 trucks with the highest priority number leave first (so get the original TourStartTime, the 4th truck gets a later one).

Comment: We have considered also the use of a shadow variable, but finding the right priority for the trucks is not as easy. They drive at different costs and have different loading capacities. So I want to avoid any pre-determination of assignments 'vehicle' to 'customer', because there are also time-related constraints (customer time window) to fulfill. To reduce complexity we are now going to plan the tours with a unique and late tour_start (i.e. 6pm) and distribute the tour_starts in a secondary step over the whole day.

Comment: One more little question: The previous limitation, that chained planning_enities are not nullable still exists with Optaplanner V6.3 ?

Comment: See (and vote for) [PLANNER-226](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-226). Check the status (and the fix version) of that issue.